# I want to store a value even after my program ends

Tags: c++, file-io, storage

I want to store a letter into a variable so that whenever the program starts again it can use the variable in further program execution.

What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: If it would have been possible then there should be no concept of file and folders

Comment: @Subinoy and _each_ program __for  must__ should have unique variable names. :-)

Comment: definitively overkill and not what you're looking for, but it would be possible to compile a dll/so ad hoc and LoadLibrary it so that it contains a func or similar which return the value. But seriously, the answer depend on your concrete needs and may or may not involve direct file access.

Comment: @wonkorealtime: On Windows that would be problematic as the DLL is read-only while running. Not impossible, but it makes the problem even harder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316152/store-data-in-executable

Comment: Even a shared memory segment would work.  That way you don't even need a file.

Answer (score 16):

No, you cannot achieve this using *variables*. *variables* only exist untill the program finishes execution. Once the program is finished, no *variable* is *retained*.

You need to make use  of *file i/o*. You can write the end (final) data of one execution to a file, the next time program runs, it can read the file contains and *resume* the exection.

For your reference,

**In `C`**

you can check below library functions

- [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)
- [`fclose()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose)
- [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)
- [`fwrite()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite)
- [`fprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)
- [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

and their families.

**In `C++`**

- [`<fstream>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)

Comment: or `<fstream>`, since C++ is included

Comment: @DonReba Thanks, i'll add that to my asnwer. :-)

Comment: I already have a output Ex: "H:\" which is stored inside LPTSTR driveNameCompelte. how can i write this into a file ??

Comment: @SouravGhosh I found this interesting, could you relate this question with your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316152/store-data-in-executable